# Loop list in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm a newbie to Python but attempting to call Google Distance Matrix API

This is how my data frame looks like

[image]

## Loading data into data frame

```
data = pd.read_csv(input_filename, encoding ='utf8')
```

I just need some help looping the list.

## Issue: It keeps on printing the entire list

```
#Column name in your input data
start_latitude_name = "Start Latitude"
start_longitude_name = "Start Longitude"

end_latitude_name = "End Latitude"
end_longitude_name = "End Longitude"

start_latitude_names = data[start_latitude_name].tolist()
end_latitude_names = data[end_latitude_name].tolist()

start_longitude_names = data[start_longitude_name].tolist()
end_longitude_names = data[end_longitude_name].tolist()


for start_latitude_name in start_latitude_names: 
    origins = start_latitude_name, start_longitude_name
    destinations = end_latitude_name, end_longitude_name
    mode = "walking"

    # Set up your distance matrix url
    distancematrix_url = "*Omitted unnecessary parts*origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode={2}&language=en-EN&key={3}".format(origins, destinations, mode, API_KEY)

    print(distancematrix_url)
```

## Current Output (From each loop)

```
# Omitted unnecessary info
origins=40.7614645,123.0,-73.9825913,456.0&destinations=40.65815,789.0,-73.98283,0.0
```

## Expected Output (From each loop)

```
origins=40.7614645,-73.9825913&destinations=40.65815,-73.98283
```

I'm sure that i'm not looping it correctly, but i have tried the answers on several post and it didn't work work for me. 
I'm open to better alternatives of looping the data. Feel free to correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to switch the variables: `startlatitude` and `start_latitude_names`. Because otherwise your loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with pandas and `df.iterrows()`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(input_filename, encoding ='utf8')

for idx, row in data.iterrows(): 
    origins = row['Start Latitude'], row['Start Longitude']
    destinations = row['End Latitude'], row['End Longitude']
    mode = "walking"

    # Set up your distance matrix url
    distancematrix_url = "*Omitted unnecessary parts*origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode={2}&language=en-EN&key={3}".format(origins, destinations, mode, API_KEY)

    print(distancematrix_url)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help. I tried this before but it didn't work for me. It still prints out the entire list.

Comment: That is strange. Can you try printing `row` and `origins` before your call of `distancematrix_url`? Does it look correct there?

Comment: Hi, i realized that i forgot to restart my kernel. Sorry about that. Silly mistake. No wonder it didn't work. Will just go ahead and mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you can vectorize this operation and use the string-representations of your coordinates:

```
import pandas as pd

# Make pandas print entire strings without truncating them
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", -1)

# Create dummy-df from your example
df = pd.DataFrame({"start_latitude": [40.76, 123.00], "start_longitude": [-73.98, 456.00], "end_latitude": [40.65, 789.00], "end_longitude": [-73.98, 0.00]})
print df

# Set globals
mode = "walking"
API_KEY = "my_key"

# Create the url strings for each row
df["distance_matrix_url"] = "origins=" + df["start_latitude"].map(str) + "," + df["start_longitude"].map(str) + "&destinations=" + df["end_latitude"].map(str) + "," + df["end_longitude"].map(str) + "&mode=" + mode + "&languge=en-EN&key=" + API_KEY

# Print results
print df
```

Output:

```
   end_latitude  end_longitude  start_latitude  start_longitude                                                                   distance_matrix_url
0  40.65        -73.98          40.76          -73.98            origins=40.76,-73.98&destinations=40.65,-73.98&mode=walking&languge=en-EN&key=my_key
1  789.00        0.00           123.00          456.00           origins=123.0,456.0&destinations=789.0,0.0&mode=walking&languge=en-EN&key=my_key
```

Is this what you're looking for?